# How to open a menu with keypresses?

Tags: jquery, menu, key-events

I am currently trying to desing my first website just for me. 
I have a menu, which is hidden by default. When you press on a button in the Navbar, it opens fine.

But I want to add the possibility to do this via keys too.  M = Open Menu ; ESC = close Menu ;

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 77) {$('#Menu').collapse('show') ;}  ;
   if (e.keyCode == 27) {$('#Menu').collapse('hide') ;}  ;
}) ;
```

While this works fine, the Problem is, that if you press the M key twice or more in a row, without pressing ESC in between, the Menu wont open again. Same with the ESC key.
Additionally, when the Menu is already opened, and you press M it re-opens, which is ugly.

So I tried to save the state of the Menu in a var called MenuToggled.
Why doesnt this work??

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //different stuff...
    var MenuToggled = 0 ;
} ;

$(document).keydown(function(e) {

     if (e.keyCode == 77) {

        if (MenuToggled == 0) {$('#Menu').collapse('show') ; var MenuToggled = 1 ;} 
     } ;   

     if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        if (MenuToggled == 1) {$('#Menu').collapse('hide') ; var MenuToggled = 0 ;} 
     } ;   

});
```

It appears, that Jquery doesnt even enter into the keycode-if's, because I tried to fire an .alert('test') ; event and it didnt work in the "second" code.

Comment: `var MenuToggled = 0 ;` will be out of scope as it is declared in the document.ready function. Move it out of there, just in the general JavaScript file

Comment: Instead of taking flag <<MenuToggled>> , use $('#Menu').is(":visible")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var menuToggled = false;
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    var action = false;

    switch(e.which){
        case 77:
            if(!menuToggled) action = 'show';
        break;

        case 27:
            if(menuToggled) action = 'hide';
        break;
    };

    if(action !== false){
        $('#Menu').collapse(action);
        menuToggled = !menuToggled;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this statment ..   `e.preventDefault()`

```
if (e.keyCode == 77) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (MenuToggled == 0) {$('#Menu').collapse('show') ; var MenuToggled = 1 ;} 
     } ;   

     if (e.keyCode == 27) {
         e.preventDefault();
        if (MenuToggled == 1) {$('#Menu').collapse('hide') ; var MenuToggled = 0 ;} 
     } ;
```